# Spring integration tests issue: could not initialize proxy - no Session through reference chain:

Tags: spring, hibernate, jackson, open-session-in-view, spring-mvc-test

I am trying to test a controller method and I have an issue that probably has to do with lazy loading and I am therefore trying to set up a open entity manager in view filter for my tests.

**Setup method:**

```
@Before
public void setup() {
    mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(wac)//
            .addFilters(springSecurityFilterChain, new OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter())//
            .defaultRequest(get("/").with(csrf())//
            .secure(true))//
            .build();//
...
```

Test method:

```
@Test
    public void shouldNotAllowAdvertisementModification() throws Exception {
        ChildminderAdvertisementInfo childminderAdvertisementInfo = new ChildminderAdvertisementInfo();
        childminderAdvertisementInfo.setAddressReference(VALID_ADDRESS_REFERENCE);
        ChildminderAdvertisement advertisement = helper.buildChildminderAdvertisement("balteo@yahoo.fr");
        childminderAdvertisementInfo.setAdvertisement(advertisement);
        CustomJacksonObjectMapper mapper = new CustomJacksonObjectMapper();
        String jsonChildminderAdvertisementInfo = mapper.writeValueAsString(childminderAdvertisementInfo);
        mockMvc.perform(post("/advertisement/childminder/edit/{advertisementId}", 1L).with(userDeatilsService("balteo@gmail.com"))//
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)//
                .header("X-Ajax", "true")//
                .content(jsonChildminderAdvertisementInfo))//
                .andDo(print())//
                .andExpect(status().isForbidden());//
    }
```

Object Mapper:

```
public class CustomJacksonObjectMapper extends ObjectMapper {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public CustomJacksonObjectMapper() {
        super();
        configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);//FIXME
        this.addMixInAnnotations(Curriculum.class, CurriculumMixin.class);
        this.addMixInAnnotations(Advertisement.class, AdvertisementMixin.class);
        this.addMixInAnnotations(Address.class, AddressMixin.class);
        this.addMixInAnnotations(Message.class, MessageMixin.class);
        this.addMixInAnnotations(Training.class, TrainingMixin.class);
        this.addMixInAnnotations(WorkExperience.class, WorkExperienceMixin.class);
    }

}
```

**Exception stack trace:**

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: could not initialize proxy - no Session (through reference chain: com.bignibou.controller.advertisement.ChildminderAdvertisementInfo["advertisement"]->com.bignibou.domain.ChildminderAdvertisement["address"]->com.bignibou.domain.Address_$$_jvst68_a["reference"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:232)
    at
```

It seem the second filter is ignored by Spring Mvc Test and I still get the hibernate error... Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I sorted the issue by:

Adding the following dependency to my project:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-datatype-hibernate4</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Registering a Hibernate jackson module on my ObjectMapper as follows:

```
CustomJacksonObjectMapper mapper = new CustomJacksonObjectMapper();
mapper.registerModule(new Hibernate4Module());
```